# JSSOR - how to autoplay and stop a video

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

How to start a video when slided to (or shown) and stopped when slided out (or hidden) and the process is repeated when the slides continues on loop?

I basically have the following slides:

> ```
>     <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
>         <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
>             <img data-u="image" src="img/02.jpg" />
>         </div>
>         <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
>             <img data-u="image" src="img/04.jpg" />
>         </div>
>         <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
>             <img data-u="image" src="img/05.jpg" />
>         </div>
>         <div data-p="112.50" style="display: none;">
>             <img data-u="image" src="img/09.jpg" />
>         </div>
>        <div data-p="112.50" idle='10000' style="display: none;">
>             <video id='video1' width="600" height="300" autoplay>
>                 <source src="img/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">                                
>             </video>             
>         </div>
>     </div>
> ```

The video essentially keeps playing even when slided out and displays another image.

What I'd like to basically do is stop the video from playing when the slider moves to the next index in the slides and start from the beginning when the video is shown again.

I've also tried something like this:

> ```
> function OnSlidePark(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
>     var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 
>     if (slideIndex == 4)
>     {
>         setTimeout(function()
>         {
>         console.log('Playing');
>         myVideo.play();            
>         },2000); //to make sure the video is fully displayed
>     }
>     else if (fromIndex == 4)
>     {
>        console.log('Paused');   //but what I really want is "Stop" or reset from the beginning of the video but at a pause until play() is called or the video is shown again.
>        myVideo1.pause();
> ```

```
    }
}
```

the console.log Playing and Paused are displayed and triggered correctly, the start and pause just doesn't work.

Let me clarify the "start" claim.  It appears that it kinda start but it just stays motionless or displays a black screen but that's probably because the video starts out with black screen and it just pauses maybe?  If I manually start the video by displaying the control, it actually plays, it just doesn't pause when the "pause" method is called.

I've also added a video outside the slide container and the video properly start and paused when the $JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK is called.

Regardless, I need the video to be stopped not paused and played from the beginning when it gets its turn again from the looping slides.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this event:

$JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE

for when:

if(progress == idleBegin) to play the video.

To pause, however, I couldn't get this one to fire:

if(progress == idleEnd)

Instead, inside the progress==idlBegin condition, i had to set a timeout to run the pause() command just right before the idle finishes.

Comment: Hmm.. I spoke too soon.  The solution above only works with Firefox and IE.  It does not work with Chrome.

Comment: did u find any solution?